# UITableView with many images high memory usage

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, memory, uiimage

Hi i am using MKMapSnapshotter to generate map images and cache them using SDWebImage. The map images will be displayed in each uitableview cell.

The problem i'm having is for about 30 uitableview cells the memory used is 130 MB, if i don't use map images the memory used is 25 MB, and finally using map images but without caching(as in generating the map image every time a cell is displayed) the memory used is 50 MB.

How can i reduce the memory usage? Or how can i store the images so they take up less memory space? Any help would be appreciated.
The code i have is below.

At the top of the class:

```
var imageCache: SDImageCache!
var mySnapOptions: MKMapSnapshotOptions!
let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 300
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)
```

In viewDidLoad():

```
imageCache = SDImageCache(namespace: "myNamespace")
mySnapOptions = MKMapSnapshotOptions()
mySnapOptions.scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
```

And in cellForRow:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> TableViewCell? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    if let post = object {
        cell.mapImageView.image = UIImage(named: "MapPlaceholder")

        let tempLoc = post["location"] as! PFGeoPoint
        let loc = CLLocation(latitude: tempLoc.latitude, longitude: tempLoc.longitude)

        imageCache.queryDiskCacheForKey(post.objectId, done: {(image: UIImage?, cacheType: SDImageCacheType!) in
            if let cachedImage = image {
                cell.mapImageView.image = cachedImage
            }else {
                cell.mapPinImageView.hidden = true
                cell.mapActivityIndicator.startAnimating()

                dispatch_async(self.queue) { () -> Void in
                    self.mySnapOptions.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc.coordinate,
                        self.regionRadius * 2.0, self.regionRadius * 2.0)
                    self.mySnapOptions.size = (cell.mapImageView.image?.size)!

                    MKMapSnapshotter(options: self.mySnapOptions).startWithCompletionHandler { snapshot, error in
                        guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
                            print("Snapshot error: \(error)")
                            return
                        }
                        self.imageCache.storeImage(snapshot.image, forKey: post.objectId, toDisk: true)
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            cell.mapActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                            cell.mapImageView.image = snapshot.image
                            cell.mapPinImageView.hidden = false
                        })
                    }

                    //
                }
            }
        })


    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: i'd turn down the scale and see if that helps

Comment: @DavidYangLiu reducing the scale from 3x to 2x does improve memory usage a bit, from 130 MB to 85 MB. But images are not as sharp. I don't think this is a desired solution, but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: yea bud don't think you can have your cake and eat it too.. its either you take the hit for having all these in memory or you cut down on the res of the images. or the last thing is to make the load of the images async and render it on screen when loading is done. but if the use scrolls past the cell cancel all work in progress. That way you don't have to cache the images BUT you may run in to empty images while scrolling and then later they fill in

Comment: Ideally I would like to store them in memory, from what i read whats stored in memory for an image is width*height*4 . Which uses alot of memory when you have a lot of images. How do modern apps that are image heavy do this kind of thing?

Comment: I really don't understand how people use the MapKit framework... maybe I'm too stupid. I started with a `MKMapView` in a collection view cell which caused major memory problems (no memory cleanup after deallocation). Then I switched to `MKMapSnapshotter`, which was already a tradeoff since the map section was non interactive. But even this solution caused a 5mb rise memory for every cell, which eventually dropped back to 80mb (from 120mb). The images itself are 144kb. Why the heck are the loaded tiles cached so aggressively?

Comment: @Alex I ended up using fast image cache to cache the images generated by the snapshotter. Memory usage ended up to be around 50mb no matter how many cells you have.

Comment: My problem is that I have an application that also shows 360 videos, so just before I start a 360 video I need to make sure that I let go of as much memory as I can. Since the MapKit framework is so crazy about caching it's assets/tiles, I just cannot use it since the app crashes or there is not enough memory to create the frame buffer

Comment: @Alex I know nothing about combining videos with images, guess you'll have to do research on optimisation

Comment: I just have a very performance critical application, so I need to be in control of the memory being allocated :) Do you also see memory not being freed after using `MKMapSnapshotter`?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a different caching framework. FastImageCache, allowed me to achieve the desired results with great scrolling performance, and low memory usage, as the images are not stored in memory but rather on disk (this is how FastImageCache works).